# How to detect Docker failure error code on auto restart?

Tags: docker

If I have run a container with `--restart on-failure` and the container restarts, how do I see the error code to which the container restarted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker inspect CONTAINER` provides the `State->Status` property but in case of 
restart option enabled such as `--restart on-failure` or any other option that restarts automatically the container, the `Status` value will not help about the state of the previous run but if you execute `inspect` in a loop and that you check the `Status` until it changes.

A straighter option would be to use `docker events`.
But that may produce many logs with the default configuration if you have multiple running containers.
A better option would be to filter to that container:

```
docker events --filter container=CONTAINER
```

Here an example of `docker events` output with a Jenkins container that fails (I helped it by sending a `SIGKILL` to the associated host process)  :

```
2020-03-09T19:12:19.047823892+01:00 container die 0c1d117d5b305b8ff9347024d6180be62192b5961f9d575f49c9e3c6f1f526ae (exitCode=137, image=my-jenkins:1.19.0, name=my-jenkins)
2020-03-09T19:12:19.621459228+01:00 container start 0c1d117d5b305b8ff9347024d6180be62192b5961f9d575f49c9e3c6f1f526ae (image=my-jenkins:1.19.0, name=my-jenkins)
2020-03-09T19:12:19.628964589+01:00 container attach 0c1d117d5b305b8ff9347024d6180be62192b5961f9d575f49c9e3c6f1f526ae (image=my-jenkins:1.19.0, name=my-jenkins)
```

You could also filter about the `event` values if you know what value you want to track.
[More information here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I would have to keep the terminal open and running where I run `docker events --filter container=CONTAINER ` right? As `docker events` simply is a live view of the docker state.

Comment: Yes or you can also run that in background and spool it in a specific file if makes more sense.

Comment: Makes sense. However, once I close the connection via ssh the command dies and the output file that should show docker events does not log data. How to make it keep logging the data all the time? @davidxxx

Comment: You should run the `docker events` command in a way that ignores the hang hup signal (the terminal closing signal). For example with `nohup` such as  `nohup docker events &> /foobar/events.log &`